# Poincare Patch covers half of the hyperboloid of AdS

Tags: ads-cft, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

We start with the general case of $AdS_{p+2}$ i.e AdS space in $p+2$ dimension.
\begin{equation}
X_{0}^{2}+X_{p+2}^{2}-\sum_{i=1}^{p+1}X_{i}^{2} = R^2
\end{equation}
This space has an isometry $SO(2,p+1)$ and is homogeneous and isotropic. The Poincare Patch is given by
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = R^{2}\left(\frac{du^2}{u^2}+u^2(-dt^2 +d\mathbf{x}^{2})\right)
\end{equation}
According to Equation (2.27) of the article http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905111, The second metric covers only half of the hyperboloid. Firstly, how do I show this. Secondly, when I go to the asymptotic limit (small radial distance), should the topology of the two spaces be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be shown by conformal compactification of the spacetime, i.e. using coordinates which allow you to draw a penrose diagram. After you have done so, you can analytically continue the geometry and discover the other half (see chapter 2 of [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0689)) . Regarding differences in topology: I don't see any reason for this to be the case.